# How to format a table

Tags: tables

I am trying to have a regression output from Python straight into LaTeX, to no avail. I found a sequence of three errors:

1. Eliminate \\
2. Add [t] on top
3. Eliminate \hline

Even applying all these manual changes, the output from Python did not work. 
What am I missing here?

The full non-working example is below. As I am not sure which package interferes with the results, I added all of them.

```
\documentclass[15pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Dresden}   
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usefonttheme{serif} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table - OLS Regressions} \\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
                          & Model 1  & Model 2  & Model 3  & Model 4   \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
ALTERNATIVE0[T.True]      & -0.01*** & -0.01*** & -0.01*** & -0.01***  \\
                          & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)    \\
FPM\_DISTRIBUTION[T.True] & 0.02***  & 0.01***  & 0.02***  & 0.02***   \\
                          & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)    \\
Intercept                 & 0.60***  & 0.90     & 0.61***  & 0.02***   \\
                          & (0.01)   & (0.64)   & (0.01)   & (0.00)    \\
unemployment              &          & -0.00    &          &           \\
                          &          & (0.01)   &          &           \\
Log-likelihood            & 506.85   & 510.85   & 260.65   & 260.65    \\
R-squared Adj             & 0.98     & 0.98     & 0.98     & 0.98      \\
AIC                       & -931.69  & -929.70  & -477.31  & -477.31   \\
BIC                       & -806.65  & -789.41  & -424.90  & -424.90   \\
No. observations          & 156      & 156      & 80       & 80        \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Putting the head rows in a different `tabular` environment than the content is wrong, the alignment won't match. Also your table is too wide for a beamer frame. Consider shortening the contents of the left most column.

Comment: I edited since it is not related with Python.

Comment: Also a `\small` could help. And don't use `\hline\hline`, instead consider using `booktabs` and its `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.

Comment: Thanks @Sigur but I disagree. The idea is to have the table automatically outputted from Python. If Python outputs and the table needs tampering than the python function is not good, right. That's my point. How come there is a function `as\_látex()` in python that does not work?

Comment: @BFurtado, your code has no python code so, to us, it is the same as you had typed by hand. We need more info to reproduce your code and see the problem. In your code, the problem was wrong way to use tabular head, as mentioned. Consider edit and improve your code.

Comment: Also you should load `hyperref` last.

Comment: @Skillmon - The `beamer` document class loads the `hyperref` package automatically. :-)

Comment: besides `hyperref` you also don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{color}` with beamer

Comment: @Mico you are right, but I meant in general, you should load `hyperref` last (and I know there are exceptions to that rule of thumb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following does fit on the frame and looks not too bad.

```
\documentclass[15pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Dresden}   
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usefonttheme{serif} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table - OLS Regressions}
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{l*4r}
    \toprule
                      & Model 1  & Model 2  & Model 3  & Model 4   \\
    \midrule
    ALTERNATIVE0      & -0.01*** & -0.01*** & -0.01*** & -0.01***  \\
                      & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)    \\
    FPM\_DISTRIBUTION & 0.02***  & 0.01***  & 0.02***  & 0.02***   \\
                      & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)    \\
    Intercept         & 0.60***  & 0.90     & 0.61***  & 0.02***   \\
                      & (0.01)   & (0.64)   & (0.01)   & (0.00)    \\
    unemployment      &          & -0.00    &          &           \\
                      &          & (0.01)   &          &           \\
    Log-likelihood    & 506.85   & 510.85   & 260.65   & 260.65    \\
    R-squared Adj     & 0.98     & 0.98     & 0.98     & 0.98      \\
    AIC               & -931.69  & -929.70  & -477.31  & -477.31   \\
    BIC               & -806.65  & -789.41  & -424.90  & -424.90   \\
    No. observations  & 156      & 156      & 80       & 80        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since `table` and `figure` environments don't "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word) in `beamer` documents, there's no point in using a `table` "wrapper" and incurring the associated overhead. Just place the table's caption in the frame title.

Do try to make your table more readable by aligning all numbers on their explicit or implicit decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%    \usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%    \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%    \usepackage{graphicx}
%    \usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % <-- new
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Table --- OLS Regressions}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\small
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{2.5}}}
    \toprule
    & \mc{Model 1} & \mc{Model 2} & \mc{Model 3} & \mc{Model 4}   \\
    \midrule
    ALTERNATIVE0      & -0.01^{***} & -0.01^{***} & -0.01^{***} & -0.01^{***}  \\
                      & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)    \\
    FPM\_DISTRIBUTION & 0.02^{***}  & 0.01^{***}  & 0.02^{***}  & 0.02^{***}   \\
                      & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)   & (0.00)    \\
    Intercept         & 0.60^{***}  & 0.90     & 0.61^{***}  & 0.02^{***}   \\
                      & (0.01)   & (0.64)   & (0.01)   & (0.00)    \\
    Unemployment      &          & -0.00    &          &           \\
                      &          & (0.01)   &          &           \\
    \addlinespace 
    Log-likelihood    & 506.85   & 510.85   & 260.65   & 260.65    \\
    Adj.\ R-squared   & 0.98     & 0.98     & 0.98     & 0.98      \\
    AIC               & -931.69  & -929.70  & -477.31  & -477.31   \\
    BIC               & -806.65  & -789.41  & -424.90  & -424.90   \\
    No.\ observations & 156 & 156 & 80 & 80 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```